# How to check which ID that has all the different values of another attribute?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table like this:

```
+--------+--------+
| userID | itemID |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      3 |
|      1 |      4 |
|      2 |      3 |
|      2 |      4 |
|      3 |      4 |
+--------+--------+
```

I am trying to select all the userID's that has all the different itemID's.
Meaning, if I were to expand itemID's in the future to have itemID 5 too, the same query would select all the userID's that has itemID 3, 4 and 5.

I've struggled with this problem for several hours now, but not managed to find the general query I am looking for.. I would appreciate all the help I could get!

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select userid
from t
group by userid
having count(distinct itemid) = (select count(distinct t2.itemid) from t t2);
```